# UIScrollView with "Layers"

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

Sorry about the title, but I don't know how to say what I want.

I want a UIScrollView with layers, like a image and a text above it, and when it is scrolled, the text is moved faster than the image. Like [this video](http://vimeo.com/30783282), exactly at 0:13; I've thought about a UIScrollView inside a UIScrollView, but would not be something really good.

Thanks for the attention, 
Alberto

Comment: The effect you're looking for is called "parallax scrolling".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could place an instance of `UIImageView` behind your `UIScrollView`. When the method [scrollViewDidScroll](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a) is called, you can easily change the position of your background view dependent on the offset of the scrollView.